# How to read other than current attribute values in jpa AttributeConverter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to access other than current annotated attribute in AttributeConverter.

I have a java class having two attributes. Out of two, one is annotated with @Convert.

```
@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
private Long creationDate;

@Column(name = "CARD_DISPLAY_NAME")
@Convert(converter = ConverterCard.class)
private String cardDisplayName;
```

I want to access the value of creationDate column in the AttributeConverter class for cardDisplayName

```
@Converter
public class ConverterCard implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
    
    //want to access the value of creationDate column
    return null;
}

@Override
public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    
    //want to access the value of creationDate column
   return null

}
```

}

Comment: It's currently not possible, there are more details in the link -  [Coverters based on multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172083/creating-converters-based-on-multiple-attributes-in-jpa-2-1).